# Short way to write if exists else

Tags: python, expression, default

What I want to do is :

```
if myObject:  # (not None)
    attr = myObject.someAttr
else:
    attr = ''
```

And avoiding if possible, ternary expressions. Is there something like :

```
attr = myObject.someAttr || '' ?
```

I was thinking of creating my own function such as :

```
get_attr_or_default(instance,attr,default):
    if instance:
        return instance.get_attribute(attr)
    else:
        return default
```

But I would be surprised to hear that python doesn't have a shortcut for this.

**Synthesis :**

I tried both of solutions and here's the result :

```
class myClass(Models.model):
    myObject = model.foreignKey('AnotherClass')

class AnotherClass(Models.model):
    attribute = models.charField(max_length=100,default = '')


attr = myClass.myObject.attribute if myClass.myObject else '' # WORKED
attr = myClass.myObject and myClass.myObject.attribute # WORKED with NONE as result
attr = myClass.myObject.attribute or ''  # Raises an error (myObject doesn't have attribute attribute)
try: attr = myClass.myObject.attribute
except AttributeError: attr = ''  # Worked
```

Thanks for your answers !

Comment: why "avoiding if possible, ternary expressions" ??? That's exactly what they are for. Also, beware that `bool(myObject)` can eval to `False` even if `myObject is not None` - empty strings / lists / tuples / dicts / sets, numeric zeros (int / float etc) and quite a few other (non builtin) types have a false value in a boolean context.

Comment: Well, I was told to avoid ternary expression if possible because it's harder to read but I realised that ternary expressions aren't so hard to understand (not like PHP for instance)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[6.11. Conditional expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions)

```
attr = myObject.someAttr if myObject else ""
```

Comment: @traceur it is first thing came to mind so I added this. Other answers better explains. :) thanks though.

Comment: The most idiomatic answer so far.

Answer (score 3):

This will set `attr` to `None` if `myObject` is `None` and `someAttr` if it a proper object.

```
attr = myObject and myObject.someAttr
```

The evaluation on the right-hand side is only performed if required for the value, see [Python Docs](http://www.itmaybeahack.com/homepage/books/nonprog/html/p05_control/p05_c03_advlogic.html#taking-other-short-cuts), which say:

> In the case of and, if the left-hand side is equivalent to False, the
>   right-hand side is not evaluated, and the left-hand value is returned.

This is the same pattern as the `??` null-coalsecing operator that C# has, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx.

Note that this will not work well if you have a boolean operator on your object. If so, you need to use `myObject is not None`.

Comment: @barr I used to find Python's and/or hard to parse in general because I've been doing C++ for 20 years, but I think that with good syntax highlighting the keyword pops out. Eventually, you get used to it, just like everything else.

Comment: @Macke I didn't mean in that sense, I meant more in the sense that it wasn't immediately obvious to me what this would do in various circumstances.

Comment: Macke instead of linking C# I would like to *suggest* you to add *`In the case of and, if the left-hand side is equivalent to False, the right-hand side is not evaluated, and the left-hand value is returned.`* from [Python docs](http://www.itmaybeahack.com/homepage/books/nonprog/html/p05_control/p05_c03_advlogic.html#taking-other-short-cuts)

Comment: It's not quite what the OP wanted. The difference is when myObject is None: The answer returns None, the OP wanted ''. In many cases, this will not change the functionality of the program, but there may be edge cases where it does make a difference, e.g. if some library explicitly nneds a str object.

Answer (score 2):

Cool way (even w/out ternary expressions):

```
attr = getattr(myObject or object(), 'someAttr', '')
```

[`object()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=object#object) returns a new featureless object (quoting the documentation).

`myObject or object()` will return `object()` if `myObject` is empty.

Logic:

```
    myObject is empty?
          / \
         /   \ N
        /     \ 
     Y /    getattr(myObject, ...) returns that attribute 
      /          
     /
    /
getattr(object(), ...) will produce '' (empty string)
```

Answer (score 1):

At best you can do:

```
try:
    attr = myObject.someAttr
except AttributeError:
    attr = ''
```

Comment: @traceur, What do you mean?

Comment: Don't use bare `except`, be more specific so `except AttributeError:`.

Comment: @AlexThornton, Thank you very much. I have updated the answer accordingly

Comment: @traceur, Thank you very much. I have updated the answer accordingly

Comment: This goes against the PEP8 guidelines (http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: Having everything on two lines. Look under the "Other Recommendations" section of PEP8. "While sometimes it's okay to put an if/for/while with a small body on the same line, never do this for multi-clause statements. Also avoid folding such long lines!"

Answer (score 1):

If you really insist on doing things in strange, convoluted and tricky way, you could try:

```
val = (myObject is not None and myObject.attr) or default
```

which is the old (and quite controversial) pre-ternary-expression idiom. Note that this will **NOT** work as expected if `bool(myObject.attr)` evals to `False` (which will be the case for most empty containers, empty strings, numeric zeros and quite a few non-builtin types).

TL;DR : use the ternary expression, that's what it's for.

Answer (score 0):

What you suggested yourself, but slightly different:

```
if myObject:
    attr = myObject.someAttr or ''
```

If `myObject.someAttr` is `None` it will ignore it and put `''` in `attr`

Comment: This will fail if myObject is None.

Comment: @hvb I assumed he'd still use the `if myObject:` check. I'll make an edit